# Windows Batch File (.bat) corrupted

Tags: windows-10, batch, batch-file

i was searching google to find a way to hide images/files in my computer. That's when I came across .bat file. I followed the [steps](https://www.wikihow.com/Hide-Files-and-Folders-Using-Batch-Files), I setup the password shown in the steps. The .bat file was working well, TO ADD : I was using the .bat file in my External Hard drive to store photos.

Now suddenly the .bat is not opening up, it just asks "Lock the folder (Y/N)". If anyone knows how to retrieve my pictures please let me know. Almost 1.5gb of pictures and files are lost.

Comment: the file in your link does not ask `Lock the folder (Y/N)`. Did you use a different batch file or did you edit the file?

Comment: Did you read the tips on the link you provided? Did you try it? `If you've made a mistake in editing the code and hidden some files then run cmd and then go to the folder which contained those files and then type attrib -r -h -s *.* then hit enter and your files will come back.`

Comment: Your question does not contain enough information to be answered without our making assumptions. Please include the code of your batch file *as it currently exists on your system*.

Comment: And make sure not to use the External drive any more in case the pictures got deleted somehow. If you do the chances are less to recover them.

Answer (score 2):

The folder is still where you left it. All this `.bat` file did was to mark it as
hidden, which is not any kind of protection, except from people that are beginners
in Windows.

To access the folder:

- Start Windows Explorer (or press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>)
- Click "View" at the top
- Click "Options" on top-tight
- Click "View"
- Under "Hidden f‌iles and folders" click next to
  "Show hidden f‌iles, folders, and drives"
- Click OK
- Position to your folder, which will now be visible.

From now on, this folder will keep its Hidden attribute, but will be visible in
Explorer. If you wish to undo this attribute:

- In Explorer, right-click the folder
- Select Properties
- In the General tab, click next to "Hidden" so it becomes unchecked
- Click OK

I would advise to not use this `.bat` file, but use instead the above method.

Comment: How do you figure the files are only hidden?

Comment: @Albin: I have downloaded the `.bat` file. All it does is call `attr`.

Comment: this can not be the file the OP uses, either he edited it or he used a different one (see my question's comment).

Comment: @Albin: He might be using two different `.bat` files, but my answer tells how he can get his data back and stop using `.bat` files for elementary Windows operations.

Comment: In case of lost data, you really shouldn't poke around in the dark. I know you need/want the point for answers, but please restrict yourself. In case he deleted the files accidentally you might make things worse by throwing him things to try. Otherwise, thanks for your big support here on superuser...!!

Comment: @Albin: If he cannot see the folder after what I proposed, then the folder is not there, certainly. But with my answer he can be sure of what he is seeing. And please don't derogate my attempts to help posters to the low level of "want the point". I haven't worked on such a detailed answer just for a point. I don't like your comment.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to offend you. Never mind my comment about the points. I'm not saying your solution won't work (in fact it probable will) but still there is no need to poke around an **possibly** make things worse. At least he should do a sector image first before accessing the drive again. (or post the actual batch file he used, to make sure the suggestions don't do any harm)

Comment: @Albin: I think you would be talking over his head in that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100082/discussion-between-albin-and-harrymc).